# Python for loops not iterating over 2nd condition correctly

Tags: python, list, for-loop, while-loop, tuples

I have a long list of tuples that take the form

```
num_list = [('A1', 4, 'FF', 977.98), ('A4', 14, 'CC', 249.12), ('A1', 14, 'EE', 386.42), ('A9', 19, 'BB', 919.21), ('A4', 14, 'CC', 109.80)]
```

The first element of each tuple corresponds to an ID, the second what day an event occurred, the third the category of the event and the fourth the value of the event.

The task is to print out the maximum value in the previous 5 days, eg on day 6 only events from days 1 to 5 should be considered, for each separate ID i.e. something of the basic form

```
Day   ID    Max
7     A1    400
7     A2    350
8     A1    750
```

Currently I have the following code after num_list is declared where ID is a set of all the ID values. 14 and 18 are used as the days goes up to day 19

```
first_value = 1
fifth_value = 5

for id in ID:
    while first_value <= 14 and fifth_value <= 18:
        result = max([i for i in num_list if i[1] <= fifth_value and i[1] >= first_value and i[0] == id], key = lambda  x:x[3])
        first_value += 1
        fifth_value += 1
        print(f"result[0]} {result[1]} {result[3]}")
```

The problem is that this is only returning the maximum results for the first ID, A1 in this case. This it is doing correctly but I'm not sure why it's not doing it for every ID. I've checked and before the while loop it is returning every ID so I'm not sure what the problem is here

Thanks in advance, sorry if something similar has been posted before but I couldn't find it

Comment: Isn't there an `{` missing in your `f` string?

Comment: I've added a little snippet of code to find the highest value on a range of days. Hope you take a look on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're after, but here are my 2 cents. Note that `id` is a reserved variable name in Python. (hence the usage of `id_`)

```
#Let's say we have the data shown in the `num_list`.

num_list = [('A1', 4, 'FF', 977.98), ('A4', 14, 'CC', 249.12), ('A1', 14, 'EE', 386.42), ('A9', 19, 'BB', 919.21), ('A4', 14, 'CC', 109.80), ('A7', 6, 'DD', 243.12), ('A3', 11, 'GG', 612.21)]

#First, we want to sort it by the `day` of occurence. Then we want to list all the possible IDs.

sorted_list = sorted(num_list, key=lambda x:x[1])
ID = sorted(list(set(x[0] for x in num_list)))

# Then, let's define a function, which will get the entry/row with the maximum value
# We give the function two arguments. The `day`, which is the day of observation.
#    If the day of observation is 6, then, only look at the entries which have day of the event 1-5
# The another argument is the id_ we are looking at ('A1', 'A4', ..etc.)

def get_max_within_time_window(day, id_):

    # Get all the entries with the wanted id
    entries_id = [x for x in sorted_list if x[0] == id_]

    # Get all the entries within the 5-day time window. The day of observation not included.
    entries_filtered = [x for x in entries_id if 0 < day-x[1] <= 5]

    # In case of zero matches, return empty list
    if not entries_filtered:
        return []

    # Return the event with highest `value`
    return max(entries_filtered, key=lambda x:x[3])

# Now, let's put this in action.
# Day*: The day of observation
# Day: The day of event occurence. If day of observation is 6, then day of occurence can be 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5.
print('Day*\tDay\tID\tMax')
for day in range(20):
    for id_ in ID:
        found = get_max_within_time_window(day, id_)
        if not found:
            continue
        max_val = found[3]
        day_occured = found[1]
        print(f'{day}\t{day_occured}\t{id_}\t{max_val}')
```

## Results

```
Day*    Day     ID      Max
5       4       A1      977.98
6       4       A1      977.98
7       4       A1      977.98
7       6       A7      243.12
8       4       A1      977.98
8       6       A7      243.12
9       4       A1      977.98
9       6       A7      243.12
10      6       A7      243.12
11      6       A7      243.12
12      11      A3      612.21
13      11      A3      612.21
14      11      A3      612.21
15      14      A1      386.42
15      11      A3      612.21
15      14      A4      249.12
16      14      A1      386.42
16      11      A3      612.21
16      14      A4      249.12
17      14      A1      386.42
17      14      A4      249.12
18      14      A1      386.42
18      14      A4      249.12
19      14      A1      386.42
19      14      A4      249.12
```

Comment: If I wanted to add another column with the average in the same range after the max column, could I define it in the same way as here?

Comment: Sure. If the average is calculated from the set `entries_filtered` in `get_max_within_time_window`, you could add the calculation of the average in that function (and perhaps rename it to `get_max_and_average`). Should you have any problems with this, you may ask here in the comments or add a new question.

Comment: I ended up defining a new function get_avg_within_time_window in a similair way here. I used np.mean on the return section but I'm getting the following error File "Question_3.py", line 59, in get_avg_within_time_window
    return np.mean(entries_filtered_avg, key = lambda x:x[3])
TypeError: mean() got an unexpected keyword argument 'key'

Answer (score 0):

With your example I can access quite easily to any range of tuples:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

num_list = [('A1', 4, 'FF', 977.98), ('A4', 14, 'CC', 249.12), ('A1', 14, 'EE', 386.42), ('A9', 19, 'BB', 919.21), ('A4', 14, 'CC', 109.80)]

print [item for item in num_list if item[1] < 19 ]
```

> **Output:**

```
mortiz@alberta:~/Documents/projects/python$ python tuples.py 
[('A1', 4, 'FF', 977.98), ('A4', 14, 'CC', 249.12), ('A1', 14, 'EE', 386.42), ('A4', 14, 'CC', 109.8)]
```

> **If you want a range then change it using range():**

```
print [item for item in num_list if item[1] in range(5,19) ]
```

> **Output:**

```
mortiz@alberta:~/Documents/projects/python$ python tuples.py 
[('A4', 14, 'CC', 249.12), ('A1', 14, 'EE', 386.42), ('A4', 14, 'CC', 109.8)]
```

> **Finally, the highest value of the selected range:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

num_list = [('A1', 4, 'FF', 977.98), ('A4', 14, 'CC', 249.12), ('A1', 14, 'EE', 386.42), ('A9', 19, 'BB', 919.21), ('A4', 14, 'CC', 109.80)]
result=[item for item in num_list if item[1] in range(5,19)]
highest=[item[3] for item in result]

print max(highest)
```

> **Output (highest value)**

```
mortiz@alberta:~/Documents/projects/python$ python tuples.py
386.42
```

Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

First, you have a missing opening curly brace for `result[0]` in this line 

`print(f"result[0]} {result[1]} {result[3]}")`

but your main problem is that in your while loop, `first_value` and `fifth_value` keep getting incremented while the while loop runs for the first id, but then they are never reset, so for each subsequent id you never enter the while loop.

Comment: Yeah missed the { when I copied and pasted the code in. How would you recommend that I reset the loop then

Comment: If I understand how your code is supposed to work, just move your initialization of `first_value` and `fifth_value` to right above and at the same level of indentation as your while statement.

Comment: Thanks that now works for the first two IDs i.e. prints out the 14 sets of data for the first two IDs. But after two entries for the third ID i get ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence

Comment: If your list comprehension is returning an empty list because nothing in `num_list` matches `i[1] <= fifth_value and i[1] >= first_value and i[0] == id`, then you'll get an error trying to find the max of an empty list.

Comment: So why do you think it's returning an empty list but only after a number of outputs have been printed to the console

Comment: Presumably because as you're looping through `id` values and incrementing `first_value` and `fifth_value`for some combinations nothing in `num_list` will match `i[1] <= fifth_value and i[1] >= first_value and i[0] == id`. For debugging purposes, have your code print the values of `id` and `first_value` and `fifth_value` at the beginning of each iteration of the while loop, so that when it crashes you can see exactly which values are not there in `num_list`, and think about how you want to handle that.